# why isp avr MCU doesn't need ground?

Tags: avr, isp

Few days ago, while making my ic burner, I notice one thing very interesting and weird. It's that AVR MCU ISP interface really doesn't need to be connected to ground at all. **Why does AVR-ISP work without being connected to the ground?**

I have tested this with few same package size avr MCU: namely the atmeaga328, 48v, 88v, 88pa and 168. They all work fine without connected to the GND.

My personal guess would be that it's probably because the avr is grounded via the MISO or the MOSI pins during the ISP session, since those 2 I/O pins can be programmed to connected to VCC or Gnd.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Show us your actual schematic, this photo is completely useless - it doesn't show anything that can aid in answering your question.

Comment: By GND do you mean the pad on the bottom of the device? (I'm assuming based on your socket you are programming QFN devices).

Comment: @Tom Carpenter by gnd, I mean the gnd on the 6 pins icsp header totally disconnected! I have a button to the Gnd, and when it's disconnected, the isp function of the avr still works perfectly!!

Comment: @pipe It's a basic AVR ISP circuit with GND disconnected. You don't need a schematic, and I built it without using a schematic too. it's that simple.

Comment: @Atmega328 Ok, then I conclude that you have not connected a CPU at all, because obviously you have added the photo for a reason, right?

Comment: #pipe updated the question with more photos. Taking photo is kinda of one of my hobbit.

Comment: Expanding on pjc50's comment below regarding "phantom supply": even if you do not connect ground and/or supply a chip can still work, it then powers through the **ESD protection diodes** see this EEVBlog video for an explanation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yFh7Vv0Paw&t=1s

Comment: looking at the picture of the wiring, i suspect that you have a short to ground somewhere.   ... by the way, the pictures that you posted have nothing to do with the question ... you should remove them

Comment: @jsotola If the pictures are useless, than you really have nothing to comment about. right? So just for your sweet little comment there. it's totally worth posting the photos. I am 100% sure that it's not connected to the gnd because I have a button connected to the gnd. I maybe dumb, but I am not that stupid.

Comment: i see sloppy wiring. ... for instance, the yellow wire has the insulation mashed at one end. it is quite possible that the insulation on one of the wires is compromised someplace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably you have a sneak ground through the earth in your circuit and the USB connector on your computer to earth.

Edit: Alternately, AC signals may be capacitively coupled and DC-restored via the clamp diodes on CMOS inputs, but it's obviously not advisable to operate in this mode in most cases.

As pointed out in the comments, any pin which is low will act to bring the ground potential within a diode drop of where it should be. RESET often doesn't have a series resistor, which makes it a good candidate.

In any case, passing current deliberately through the protection diodes is bad and can lead to latchup.

Comment: I am 100% sure that it's not connected to the ground!

Comment: I don't think so. my guess: it's probably because the avr is grounded via the MISO or the MOSI pins during the ISP session, since those 2 I/O pins can be programmed to connected to VCC or Gnd. That will be my guess, but I don't really know.

Comment: Another candidate is RESET, which I think is held low during programming. You're almost certainly experiencing current flow through the protection diodes. See "phantom power"

Comment: @pjc50 of course. it only has 6 possibilities that it's connected to the Gnd, and the last possibility would be that it's doesn't need to be connected to the Gnd, which is probably less likely. The million dollar question would be which one is correct and why!?

Comment: Providing a schematic would have been a good start.